# Disable product magnification / zoom in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, zoom

I've added this to default.xml, which partially works to remove the zoom feature

```
<head>
    <remove src="Magento_Catalog::js/jquery.zoom.min.js" />
</head>
```

However, a magnifying glass still appears above the product image on the product detail page.

I've noticed sections in view.xml, specifically *vendor/magento/theme-frontend-blank/etc/view.xml* which parameterize a magnifier, one of these seems to toggle it on or off -

```
<var name="magnifier">
   <var name="enabled">false</var> <!-- Turn on/off magnifier (true/false) -->
</var>
```

This is set to false in my theme's view.xml file as well. Any idea what else I need to do to completely remove the magnification / zoom feature in Magento2?

Comment: Please look in to this file `vendor\magento\module-catalog\view\frontend\templates\product\view\gallery.phtml` Magnifier JS as well

Comment: Add view.xml complete path for more information.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Having experimented with more settings in the view.xml file, it seems changing

```
<var name="allowfullscreen">true</var>
```

to

```
<var name="allowfullscreen">false</var>
```

solved the problem.

Comment: Unfortunately this did not work for me.

Comment: Sorry to hear Stevie. Let us know your solution if you figure it out for your setup.

Comment: Your answer is incorrect as it does not actually remove the product zoom on hover. It removes the lightbox.

Comment: Hi Stevie, perhaps the lightbox and magnifying glass are something different? When I made this change the magnifying glass went away... And as I said earlier, if you want to offer up a better solution, feel free to do so...

Comment: Your method is what I used to enable the magnifier in the first place. StevieG might have another extension for zooming.

Comment: @quickshiftin, once enabled this feature, zoom effect overlaps the right-hand side content.

Comment: when i false the "allowfullscreen" option then on front end the loader is showing and no image appears just unlimited time loading please can you help me on this

Answer (score 1):

One way we disabled this was to add following CSS ;

```
 .zoomImg {
    display: none !important;
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

Comment: its working but, how we can fix with gallery widget?

Answer (score 0):

Disable product magnification / zoom in Magento 2
set false enabled var magnifier in view.xml file of theme run static-content:deploy and cache:flush cmd

Answer (score 0):

In your view.xml from theme, just replace hover with click like this

```
<var name="eventType">click</var>
```