# Magento2: Remove product image magnifier for bundle products only

Tags: magento2, product-images

How can I remove image magnifier for bundle products only.

Answer (score 1):

You have to override `etc/view.xml` in your extension and add this code

```
<vars module="Magento_Bundle">
    <var name="gallery">
        <var name="allowfullscreen">false</var> <!-- Turn on/off fullscreen (true/false) -->
    </var>
</vars>
```

You can also refer this links:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36193783/remove-default-product-gallery-in-magento-2

[Disable product magnification / zoom in Magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/141931/disable-product-magnification-zoom-in-magento-2)

May be it will work.

Comment: I've overridden view.xml in my custom theme unlike Luma theme. Also, added above code in the file. but its not working and still showing magnifier.

Comment: have you tried 2nd link for all type of product remove magnifier.

Comment: yes, i have tried it but it removes magnifier from all product types. I just want to remove it for bundle products.

Comment: try my updated answer.

Comment: No. that is also not working :(